# node js child spawn stdin stdout exe communication

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process

I am trying to communicate with and windows EXE from node.js.  I am fairly new to Node.js

Using this example as a starting point, but I can't get it to work.
http://juristr.com/blog/2014/03/integrating-node-with-csharp/

It looks like the executable isn't started because .connected is false when I run it.
I don't see where/how the executable is started.

EXE code (running from command line it works fine, returning whatever was entered)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryExe
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string line;
      do
      {
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Recieved - " + line);
          if (line == "quit")
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
      } while (line != null);
    }
  }
}
```

Node.js Code (does not seem to start the exe, connected = false)

```
    console.log('Hello world');

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var posProc = spawn('C:/path/LibraryExe.exe', []);

    posProc.stdout.once('data', function (data) {
        // write it back on the response object
        console.log('stdOut');
        writeToResponse('we got back ' + data);
    });

    posProc.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('Closed');
        writeToResponse('Library closed');
    });

    posProc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    if (posProc.connected)
        console.log('connected');
    else
        console.log('not connected');

    posProc.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';
    posProc.stdin.write('Hello');
    posProc.stdin.write('quit');
    console.log('ending');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C# code is trying to read a *line* but you're not writing any CRLF pairs to the `stdin` stream. Try this instead:

```
posProc.stdin.write('Hello\r\n');
posProc.stdin.write('quit\r\n');
```

Comment: So that works, but how come connected = false.  I even check connected inside of "posProc.stdout.once()" and it says it isn't connected there.

Comment: Don't bother looking at `connected` and the other undocumented properties for child process objects. They're implementation details that stem from the fact that child process objects are kind of based on sockets (hence the `connected` property).